# parametric equation of line 1 perpendicular to a plan

Tags: parametric

Hi I would like to find the parametric equation of the line L passing by P0 (the intersection of D1 and D2) and perpendicular to the plan having D1 and D2.

D1 and D2 are others lines.

I had to find the parametric equation of
D1:\begin{cases}
x =x+y=2 \\[2ex]
3x+y+z=5
\end{cases}
So i have found:
D1:\begin{cases}
x =\frac{-(t-3)}{2} \\[2ex]
y=\frac{t+1}{2}\\[2ex]
z=t
\end{cases}

D2:\begin{cases}
x =1-2t \\[2ex]
y=1+2t\\[2ex]
z=1-t
\end{cases}

I have found $P0(5/3, 1/3, 4/3)$

I have tried to do the vector product to find a perpendicular vector.
I have replaced t by 0 in each equations to find a new point so i have found :
AP0=[5/3-3/2, 1/3-1/3, 4/3-3/2] (a vector on D1) and BP0=[5/3-1, 1/3-1, 4/3-1] (a vector on D2). So I have found [-1/9,-1/6,-1/9] as the vector product of these 2 vectors. After I have found this equation of
L:\begin{cases}
x =5/3 -1/9t \\[2ex]
y=1/3-1/6t\\[2ex]
z=4/3
\end{cases}

but it dont pass through P0

could you help me to find my error. 
Thank you

Comment: what are $D_1$ and $D_2$?

Comment: it's two lines in the space

Comment: but they have the same parameters, this can not be!

Comment: It seems that your $z$ for $P_0$ is wrong.

Comment: And: what vectors have you used in the vector product?

Comment: i have edited my post thank

Comment: Not a good edit ! Anyway, see my hint . It seems that you have used $t=0$, and this can work, but I'v not tested your calculations.

Comment: what do you mean by it's not a good edit? Next time i will try to do a better one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

First note that from $t=1-t$ we have $t=\frac{1}{2}$ so $z=\frac{1}{2}$ for $P_0$.

To solve your problem note that the orienting vectors of the two lines are:
$$
\vec v_1=(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1)^T \qquad \vec v_2=(-2,2,1)^T
$$
so the vector $\vec v_3=\vec v_1 \times \vec v_2$ is orthogonal to the plane that contain the two lines.

So the line that you want is the line oriented by such vector $\vec v_3$ and passing thorough the point $P_0$.